# Why it's not type safe to convert base type instance to derived type object/reference

Tags: c#, .net, oop, clr

```
internal class B { }
internal class D : B { }

   class Program {

    static void Main(string[] args) {

    B dToB = new D();//will execute successfully. - line 1
    D bToD = (D) new B(); //will fail at runtime. - line 2

    }
}
```

I couldn't understand why the cast/convert from base type instance to derived type reference is NOT considered type safe?

Technically the object D contains all the features of B so it should be able act as a reference to it's base instance. Shouldn't the exception be other way around ? like, line 1 should fail but not line 2.

Is type safety comes into picture only when we try to cast/convert from a type to a totally different type? And in case of base type instance to derived type reference is NOT allowed and the other way is allowed just because by design ?

Thanks!

Karthikeyan

Comment: You can't cast `new B()` to `D` because B is not a D.  D is a B though.

Comment: Every `Dog` is an `Animal` but not every `Animal` is a `Dog`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign a `new D` to a `B` because `D` has everything `B` does, plus some extra stuff. Thus, it is safe to treat it like a `B`.

Going the other way, a `new B` does not have everything a `D` has, so if you executed a `D` specific function, or accessed a `D` specific property/member, it would fail spectacularly.

Thus, this assignment/cast is not safe, or valid.

Comment: got it thanks! I was missing the fact that the underlying type's runtime type is B but the reference is D and when we try to access D's member on B's instance it will fail.